# Angular domSanitizer bypassSecurityTrustHtml outside of property

Tags: angular, mathjax

I am trying to get MathJax and Angular to run together. I am using [ngx-mathjax](https://github.com/davidshen84/ngx-mathjax) as a MathJax integration into Angular. This is my code so far:

```
<div mathjax>
  {{ field | keepHtml }}
</div>
```

`field` contains a mixture of html (for formatting) and MathJax-formulas, e.g. `<b>This</b> is an example <b>equation</b>: \( 2x+3=2 \)`. `keepHtml` is a custom pipe, that makes use of the DomSanitizer, to bypass the html sanitation:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keepHtml',
  pure: false
})
export class KeepHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(content: string): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
}
```

I want to insert the formatted html together with rendered MathJax-equations. But I only get one thing to run:

```
<div mathjax [innerHtml]="field | keepHtml">
</div>
```

... only works once, as soon as `field` updates, MathJax doesn't update the equation anymore. When I do

```
<div mathjax>
  {{ field }}
</div>
```

the html is sanitized and therefore the html-tags are printed as text. The MathJax-equations are rendered and updated properly though. Using the `keepHtml`-Pipe outside of `innerHtml` like in the first code snippet, throws the error `SafeValue must use [property]=binding...`. How do I get everything to work together?

**Edit**

That's my MathJax-Config:

```
MathJaxModule.forRoot({
      version: '2.7.5',
      config: 'TeX-AMS_HTML',
      hostname: 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com'
}),
```

Comment: Can you tell me your `MathJaxModule.forRoot` configuration?

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: I'm trying to create a stackblitz, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I can get a reference to the directive in the template, but it's just showing plain text. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: actually posting the stackblitz link would come in handy: [stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svry8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your innerHtml update you can use the `MathJaxTypeset()` to update the view:

```
<div mathjax #math>
  {{ field | keepHtml }}
</div>
```

```
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent {
  @ViewChild('math', { static: false, read: MathJaxDirective })
  mathJax?: MathJaxDirective;

  updateField(html: string): void {
    this.field = html;

    setTimeout(() => this.mathJax.MathJaxTypeset());
  }
}
```

This is a simple example with little checking, I just assume you need to use the setTimeout to get into the next detection cycle. You can also think about using a getter and setter for the `field` and trigger it there. Perhaps you can even use the `Pipe` itself, but I'm not entirely sure

Comment: I tried that as well, but the MathJaxTypeset()- method doesn't do anything, when called. There seems to be a cached version of the changes in the MathJaxDirective which isn't updated, when you update `innerHtml`